# Building wheel for pywinpty (pyproject.toml) ... error while installing jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pywinpty
  Building wheel for pywinpty (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pywinpty (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [72 lines of output]
      Running `maturin pep517 build-wheel -i c:\users\aryal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe`
         Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.36
         Compiling unicode-xid v0.2.2
         Compiling windows_x86_64_msvc v0.29.0
         Compiling libc v0.2.117
         Compiling syn v1.0.86
      error: could not compile `windows_x86_64_msvc` due to 2 previous errors
      warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
      error: build failed
      ðŸ’¥ maturin failed
        Caused by: Failed to build a native library through cargo
        Caused by: Cargo build finished with "exit code: 101": `cargo rustc --message-format json --manifest-path Cargo.toml --release --lib --`
      ðŸ\x8d¹ Building a mixed python/rust project
      ðŸ”— Found pyo3 bindings
      ðŸ\x90\x8d Found CPython 3.8 at c:\users\aryal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe
      error: linker `link.exe` not found
        |
        = note: program not found


      note: the msvc targets depend on the msvc linker but `link.exe` was not found


      note: please ensure that VS 2013, VS 2015, VS 2017 or VS 2019 was installed with the Visual C++ option


      error: linker `link.exe` not found
        |
        = note: program not found


      note: the msvc targets depend on the msvc linker but `link.exe` was not found


      note: please ensure that VS 2013, VS 2015, VS 2017 or VS 2019 was installed with the Visual C++ option


      error: linker `link.exe` not found
        |
        = note: program not found


      note: the msvc targets depend on the msvc linker but `link.exe` was not found


      note: please ensure that VS 2013, VS 2015, VS 2017 or VS 2019 was installed with the Visual C++ option


      error: aborting due to previous error


      error: aborting due to previous error


      error: aborting due to previous error


      error: linker `link.exe` not found
        |
        = note: program not found


      note: the msvc targets depend on the msvc linker but `link.exe` was not found


      note: please ensure that VS 2013, VS 2015, VS 2017 or VS 2019 was installed with the Visual C++ option


      error: aborting due to previous error


      Error: command ['maturin', 'pep517', 'build-wheel', '-i', 'c:\\users\\aryal\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\python.exe'] returned non-zero exit status 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pywinpty
Failed to build pywinpty
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pywinpty, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

The errors that I am getting are as follows-:

1. Building wheels for collected packages: pywinpty
   Building wheel for pywinpty (pyproject.toml) ... error

2)error: could not compile `windows_x86_64_msvc` due to 2 previous errors

3)error: build failed
ðŸ’¥ maturin failed
Caused by: Failed to build a native library through cargo
Caused by: Cargo build finished with "exit code: 101": `cargo rustc --message-format json --manifest-path Cargo.toml --release --lib --`
ðŸ\x8d¹ Building a mixed python/rust project
ðŸ”— Found pyo3 bindings
ðŸ\x90\x8d Found CPython 3.8 at c:\users\aryal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe
error: linker `link.exe` not found
|
= note: program not found

4. error: linker `link.exe` not found

Comment: Your main issue might be: "*note: please ensure that VS 2013, VS 2015, VS 2017 or VS 2019 was installed with the Visual C++ option*"

Comment: I did via anaconda. IDK why it's too tough to just set up environment :(

Comment: ...uhhh I don't know what you mean by "*via Anaconda*". Your errors indicate you are missing certain compilation tools on your Windows machine, and it is telling you to check that "*VS 2013, VS 2015, VS 2017 or VS 2019 was installed with the Visual C++ option*".

Comment: I installed what you said tho.

Answer (score 5):

You get this error when your default "python" is the 32 bit.  uninstall and reinstall the 64 bit python.

Comment: How do you know this?

Comment: I have no idea how you identified this issue, but you saved my day, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, once I updated all my pip packages (including Rust & wheel) I found I had an older 32bit python release (I don't know why was there lol), finally I unistalled the 32bit python and then updated to a latest 64bit release.

```
PS C:\Users\Jules> python -c 'import sys; print(sys.version)'3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]
```